# MacOS/OSX loses connection to shared NAS drive

Tags: macos, network, nas

I am using El Capitan (latest version) on a Mac Mini and have setup a shared drive to my Synology NAS.  The connection uses SMB (have also tried AFP).

Problem: after a period of time (hours / days) the network share will disappear.

What I have tried so far: I have added the share to my login items under System Prefs > Users & Groups - this works, in that when I logon to the Mac Mini the shares are added.  However it does not stop the shares disappearing later.

I have also put the connection username & password into my keychain so that the Mac remembers.  This also works, because when I re-add the share I don't have to provide username or password.

The Mac Mini is used as a media server (Plex) and all my media is on the NAS.  This means that when Plex is used, we get occasions where Plex says there is no media.  The NAS is not powerful enough to run Plex itself.

Comment: Is your NAS set to go to sleep or auto update?

Comment: The NAS drives yes - not the NAS itself

Comment: Turn off the sleep on the NAS drives and you will see that it keeps the connection.  (I have a Synology as well)

Comment: Do I need to worry about the hard discs wearing out?  I worry about these things

Comment: Yes and no.  The Synology I have has been running for 3 years now.  One drive failed (was under warranty so replaced for free) and the other is still going strong. Then again, I bought "enterprise grade" [WD Red drives](https://goo.gl/KM0iYw).   I have my hibernation set for 3 hours which works for me, The drives are also 5400 RPM because they are for storage, not performance. So, depending on your setup, YMMV.

Comment: I have been running the NAS with hard drive sleep turned off.  The Mac Mini just lost connection again, so this is not the issue. I think OSX just sucks at networking.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for years, and eventually found out that all you need to do is turn off packet signing.
Below is a link on the apple forums place on how to do it. You need to be using SMB2/3 protocols (not AFP). 
I've never had a dropped network drive since.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205926

Simon.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review